# Why in array when I write x + 1 = 2 there is error

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I've got a problem understanding one thing.
From this picture of a tutorial :
[image]

The address x+i is given a value it's like x + i = value, so I am giving a value in x[i] for example x[1] = 2; and it is sum up in *(x+i) which takes the value stores in x + i which is for example 2.

So why in my code x + i is incorrect ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void edit(int *x);

int main()
{
    int x[10];
    int *ptr = &x[0];
    edit(ptr);

}

void edit(int *x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<11; ++i)
    {
        x+i= i;   // this line
        printf("x[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
    }
}
```

When I change `x+i= i;` into `*(x+i)=i` then it works ... I don't know how to read it from tutorial. I want to know why it doesn't work like in tutorial.

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer to write to it.

Comment: But in scanf from tutorial didn't do it. You just write a number or something and it is putted in x+i in the tutorial. So I don't understand why it doesn't work there. And why my post is being getting down votes ;<

Comment: `scanf` _needs_ a pointer. It dereferences internally.

Comment: If you understand why you wrote `*(x+i)` the first time, then you'll understand why you need to use it the second time as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you work with arrays and memory allocation, you will realize that a formula like "x + i" is not moving to a memory location of "i" places ahead.  Reviewing your code and the apparent functionality you are after, following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void edit(int *x);

int main()
{
    int x[10];
    int *ptr = x;                       /* Simpler way to reference the pointer to the array                */
    edit(ptr);

    return 0;
}

void edit(int *x)
{
    int *y;                             /* Utilize a local pointer to the integer array                     */
    y = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)        /* Traverse through the ten elements                                */
    {
        *y = i;                         /* Store the counter value within the associated memory location    */
        printf("x[%d] = %d\n", i, *y);
        y++;                            /* Increcment one integer memory position for the array             */
    }
}
```

Some points to note:

- When an array is defined, the array name (e.g. "x" in this program) is equivalent to the pointer definition, so referencing a pointer can be simplified.
- When moving within a block of memory that has been allocated for a variable array and index elements are not used, often times what is done is just utilizing the increment operation (e.g. "y++") or decrement operation (e.g. "y--")
- And, to avoid memory overflow (or smashing the memory) when the program was tested, the "for loop" limit was revised to compare against the value if "10" in lieu of "11".

With that, following was the test output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/IntegerArray/bin/Release$ ./IntegerArray 
x[0] = 0
x[1] = 1
x[2] = 2
x[3] = 3
x[4] = 4
x[5] = 5
x[6] = 6
x[7] = 7
x[8] = 8
x[9] = 9
```

Go ahead and review the refactored code.  Also, it would be helpful for you to review tutorial literature that delves into array usage and memory mapping.

Comment: I've changed `x+i` into `*(x+i)`. And it worked but your idea is also interesting ;) So the pointer y is a pointer to the address x that is a pointer to the ptr etc etc. pointer pointing a pointer in other words. Also it is true that the for loop should end at i<10. My code also wasn't wrong I assume ? And I was right that "y" pointer points to x address and the x pointer points to ptr address etc.

Comment: There is one more question I left this i<11 and I had x[10] = 10 in my program. Why it didn't overflow ? even if I change the i into i < 12 it still creates x[11] = 11. But the x array is declared only for x[10] ?

Comment: This may not be 100% accurate, but when traversing past the normal boundary of your memory allocation, you probably are experiencing undefined behavior.  Sometimes things seem to work and other times the program can fall over.  I will allow others to elaborate.

Comment: @Jackob2001, Re "*Why it didn't overflow ?*", That was an overflow. I think you mean "why didn't it crash?" Working as you might expect is a possible behaviour of code with undefined behaviour. The problem is that you can't count on that. The same code in different places might behave differently, and the code in one place might perform differently in different runs, on different machines, etc.